# How should I structure this nested JSON database to import into firebase firestore?

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database for an eCommerce website in this structure:

```
{
  "hats": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Hats",
    "routeName": "hats",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Brown Brim",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/ZYW3VTp/brown-brim.png",
        "price": 25
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Blue Beanie",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/ypkgK0X/blue-beanie.png",
        "price": 18
      }
    ]
  },
  "sneakers": {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Sneakers",
    "routeName": "sneakers",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Adidas NMD",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/0s3pdnc/adidas-nmd.png",
        "price": 220
      }
    ]
  },
  "jackets": {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Jackets",
    "routeName": "jackets",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Black Jean Shearling",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/XzcwL5s/black-shearling.png",
        "price": 125
      },
      {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Blue Jean Jacket",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/mJS6vz0/blue-jean-jacket.png",
        "price": 90
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to import it to firestore without too much hassle.
As you can see the `items` field should be a new sub-collection, but whenever I try to import it to firestore, I get this error:

```
{
  status: false,
  message: 'Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.'
}
```

Comment: You cannot create multiple documents and sub-collections in Cloud Firestore bysimply import a single JSON document in the same way as you can with the Realtime Database.  You should update your question to show the code that you are using to import the JSON document (which is not valid as it missing a leading `{`. ).

Comment: not directly, but you helped me solve this issue. I imported my JSON file to Realtime Database (never used it before) then I edited my database there, and then exported it to Firestore.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I managed to solve this issue, by importing my JSON file to Realtime Database, editing there, then exporting it to Firestore!